# Homodyne Detection of Photon Number States

Tags: quantum-optics, coherent-states

I'm currently trying to understand why you can detect the signal of single photons with homodyne detection. I found that the difference current $i_{34}$ is given by
$$i_{34}\sim -2 ⟨\Psi|_1⟨\alpha|_2\frac{1}{2i}(a^{\dagger}_2a_1 -a_1^{\dagger}a_2)|\alpha⟩_2|\Psi⟩_1=-2|\alpha|⟨\Psi|_1\frac{1}{2i}(a_1e^{-i\varphi}-a_1^{\dagger}e^{i\varphi})|\Psi⟩_1$$

with $|\alpha⟩$ being a coherent state and $\alpha=|\alpha|e^{i\varphi}$.
If $|\Psi⟩=|n⟩$, then $i_{34}$ should be zero. But I found that one can detect single-photon states with homodyne detection. Something must be wrong then.

Comment: The average photocurrent that you've written down is the expectation value of a quadrature operator. This expectation value is indeed zero for any Fock state since their Wigner functions are centered on the origin. In an actual measurement the photocurrent will fluctuate around zero, and it is these fluctuations that characterize the state.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes a lot of sense!